# React Asynchronous State Updates setState argument (function vs non-function)

Tags: reactjs

In the official React docs for State and Lifecycle methods, section "State Updates May be Asynchronous:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

They say when updating state based on previous state, we should pass a function to setState() to get the previous state as the first argument:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

It's hard to imagine how the "Wrong" way can possibly lead to problems.  What is an example of code where the "Wrong" way can lead to errors?

Answer (score 1):

For a case like this with just one call `setState` there is nothing wrong. However, since React batches state update, it's not guaranteed to work. I can give you a simple example

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 10 });
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
//The end result is count+1 instead of count+11

//This will work correctly
this.setState((state) => ({count: state.count+10 }));
this.setState((state) => ({count: state.count+1 }));
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-counter-using-react-bv11o?file=/App.js)